# doctrine2: Entity's association changes after first call

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm, entity

**i am using the latest version of doctrine: 2.3**

when you call a generated association function, the first time everything is fine:

```
$authors = $book->getBookToAuthors();
//$authors = array(5)
```

but the second time instead of returning the array of all associations it returns the last hydrated entity:

```
$authors = $book->getBookToAuthors();
//$authors = BookToAuthor entity
```

that happens even when there is nothing else happening:

```
$authors = $book->getBookToAuthors(); //will work
$authors = $book->getBookToAuthors(); //won't work
```

the function of getBookToAuthors() is:

```
public function getBookToAuthors()
{
    return $this->bookToAuthors;
}
```

and the mapping is as follows:

```
/**
 * @var BookToAuthor[]
 *
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="BookToAuthor", mappedBy="book", cascade={"persist"})
 * @JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="book_id", onDelete="cascade")
 */
private $bookToAuthors;
```

**please advise. i don't know what to do... :-(**

Comment: Does it really return an `array`? It's supposed to return an `ArrayCollection` object.

Answer (score 1):

sorry sorry sorry
it was a mistake in the association target side.
the target had One-To-One association instead of Many-To-One

if you have this problem make sure the association type in both sides is matching